# GitLab CI build stuck on pending

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I forked a gitlab project to help work on it, but my runner seems to be stuck. 
On the gitlab's details page, the runner section is blank.
I registered a runner on the same home computer that I'm debugging the project on.

My main question is what I can do to see what's causing this.
I'm not familiar with docker, so I've only done a `docker pull python:3.5` and hoped it would work. 
I don't know how to test these commands manually.
I could try `docker run python:3.5` and then enter the install and setup command, but I don't want to contaminate the docker image.

`gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: python:3.5

before_script:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt

build:
  script:
    - python setup.py build
  when: on_success
```

`/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`

```
concurrent = 4
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "Folatt's runner for ArkOS"
  url = "https://git.coderouge.co/ci"
  token = "<secret>"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "python:3.5"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
  [runners.cache]
```

docker image:

```
[folatt@ArkOS_Dev ~]$ sudo docker images
[sudo] password for folatt: 
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
python              3.5                 e1d7e43f34ca        3 weeks ago         684.4 MB
```

Comment: Have you figured out a way to monitor the status of the docker container and see what is going on?